# How to close popup on ionic2 app

Tags: ionic2

I have an ionic2 application with angular2, at one page I inject `LoadingController` and make use of it, at different location on my `app.ts` I catch all global http errors and want to display alert so I inject `AlertController` there .
So having 2 location which can at some point call a modal dialog creation and present it causing a problem that freezes the screen , I believe it is because there are 2 modals being open one on the other.
Is there any chance I can grab the current dialog and close it, or add param to create which closes any background modal ?

This is my code:

```js
export class SandboxPage implements OnInit {
    private _loadingModel;

    constructor(private _navCtrl:NavController, private _alertCtrl:AlertController , private _loadingCtrl: LoadingController ) {

    }

    ngOnInit() {

        this._loadingModel = this._loadingCtrl.create();
        this._loadingModel.present();

        let alert = this._alertCtrl.create({
            title: 'Error',
            message:"error message",
            buttons: [{
                text: 'Ok',
                handler: () => {
                    // user has clicked the alert button
                    // begin the alert's dismiss transition
                    let navTransition = alert.dismiss();
                }
            }]
        });
        //timeout the error to let other modals finish dismissing.
        setTimeout(()=>{
            alert.present();
        },500);

    }

}
```

The ok click want close the alert model, Here in this example it's on the same page so I can dismiss the loading but when on different components it's not possible to do.

Comment: I've just tested it and creating and presenting two modals at the same time works properly (the second one is presented on top of the previous one). So the exception must be happening for some other reason... Could you please include the most relevant parts of your code so we can take a look and see if we see something strange there?